# How do we prevent/discourage users to keep editing question/answer for no reason?

Tags: discussion, editing

First of all, is this the right place to post these kind of questions?

It's been few times I have seen some users are editing the question or answer for no reason. 
Even though you reject them, someone else will accept them eventually and that is what they want to take advantage of loop hole.

I might be the one not getting/seeing this thing right, but I want to raise the issue here.

Take a look: https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/98079/revisions

Comment: I think this editing is for +2 rep.

Comment: If the "edit" button on this post wasn't greyed out I'd edit it to fix your grammar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> First of all, is this the right place to post these kind of qsts?

Yes. What you can do is flag one of these questions for moderator attention and explain the issue in the "other" text field. The mods have the possibility to take action and should decide if there is need to. There's nothing more you as a user can do, except raising the issue here, as you did, to remind people not to approve edits carelessly.

Answer (score 5):

Its good that you have reported this.
Stackexchange has a number of self correction mechanisms to prevent such behaviour. It seems we found a weakness here.

Probably after flagging the post for Moderator attention, he will fast see they try to game the system and is able to handle this.

In this case the moderators should think about escalating the issue behind this to the main plattform, as it may be solveable for the future via improvement of the detection mechanics

Comment: Your third point is good one and we need to do that (I mean our moderators).

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with someone submitting a tag edit. I would suggest you approach the particular user in SE chat and ask them what their rationale is. IIRC you have the ability to reject the change on a question that you personally asked, so go ahead and reject if you feel it was an unnecessary addition.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. In above link the user added tag and later removed the same one. I believe you could get double points by doing this.

Comment: No. This kind of forgery would be caught by the moderation platform

Comment: You may not be able to get extra points using this technique, but I thought that the activity on the question would allow the question to remain higher up on the initial questions list page, at least if it is being sorted by Activity.  Although less egregious than attempting to scrape underserved rep points, it could still represent a  way to (albeit in a minor impact sort of way) game the system and keep a question higher up on the page and thus get more eyeballs and potentially more up votes.

Answer (score 3):

Having started to become more active on Magento StackExchange from being a regular contributor at Stackoverflow I can say for a fact that the *quality* of the content on this site is terrible. I often see posts that have not been proof read, have terrible English or are riddled with grammatical errors, or are covered with seemingly random formatting (bold and code blocks) which appear to be trying to emphasize certain points.

If users want to take time to improve the quality of this site, let them. If they don't have enough reputation to do it without having their edits reviewed, that's why the higher rep users review them. There's probably more of a problem in that mid-rep users (1-5k often) tend to blast through a review queue and accept or decline something without paying any attention to what it's doing, in which case seeing a very minor edit might appear to some as not worthy of approval. These users often do this to achieve badges.

At the end of the day, +2 reputation for an edit that improves the quality of a post is well spent.

**Now:** the context of that particular revision that you've linked to is obviously a waste of everyone's time.